# How to get member count of all members in every guild the bot is in

Tags: discord.js

I want to show in the status of the bot how many members all guild servers have, similar to on how much servers the bot is.

What I code here is a 10 second Status switcher (I guess), but I don't know how to actually get the member count of all servers the bot is on together.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = client => {
    const activities = [
    'with some code » !help',
    'with the console » !help',
    'with JavaScript » !help',
    `with ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers » !help`,
    `with ${client.guilds.cache.size.memberCount} users » !help`
    ]

    setInterval(() => {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1);
        const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];
    
        client.user.setActivity(newActivity);
    }, 10000);
}
```

The bot shows `with undefined users » !help` , no Error code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection.size.memberCount` isn't a thing. Either use [`Collection#reduce`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=reduce) on the `Client#guilds#cache` collection to sum up the [`Guild#memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property **or**  use `Client#users#cache#size` which shows how many cached users are in the bot's users collection.

Comment: Collections are still little overwelming for me, but i guess now its time to learn them qwq

Comment: Yep, you gotta look up on collections.